# Show if the series $\sum^{\infty}_1\sin\frac{1}{n}$ converges using the integral test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have to examine if the series $$\sum^{\infty}_1\sin\frac{1}{n}$$ converges using the integral test.

The series is given by function $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ which is positive when $x\ge 1$. The series can be written as an improper integral $$\sum^\infty_1\sin\frac{1}{x}=\int^\infty_1 \sin\frac{1}{x}dx$$
and if the improper integral converges, the series converges by the integral test.

With substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and $du=-\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ where the new bounds are $\frac{1}{1}=1$ and $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$,
$$\int^\infty_1 \sin\frac{1}{x}dx=\int^\infty_1-x^2\sin udu.$$

However, I'm not sure how to go on from here due to the $-x^2$.

Comment: I'm confused, surely for large $n$ we have $\sin {1 \over n} \ge { 1\over 2n}$? The Harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it should converge.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says it diverges.

Comment: I'm sorry I had the wrong wording for the task which I fixed now!

Comment: It's not true that $\sum^\infty_1\sin\frac{1}{x}=\int^\infty_1 \sin\frac{1}{x}dx$. You can only say that if the sum converges/diverges then the integral converges/diverges too.

Comment: If $x>0$ is close enough to $0$ then $\sin x > x/2.$ Thus if $n$ is big enough then $\sin(1/n) > 1/(2n).$ So
$$
\sum_n \sin\frac 1 n \ge \sum_n \frac 1 {2n} = +\infty.
$$
So you won't be able to show it converges using the integral test or any other test.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\frac{1}{n}=\int_{1}^\infty\sin\frac{1}{x}dx$, it is that the two converge or diverge simultaneously. We can provide an upper and lower bound for the integral in terms of the sum plus some constants, be they will differ in general.

As for your $x^2$, we set $u=\frac{1}{x}$, so $x=\frac{1}{u}$, so you are interested in the convergence of the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u^2}\sin(u)du$$ which diverges.

To see that this diverges, we use the inequality $\sin(u)\geq u-\frac{u^3}{6}$ for $u$ small. Then since $\sin(u)\geq 0$ for $u\in[0,1]$, we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^2}\sin(u)du\geq \int_0^\epsilon\frac{1}{u^2}\sin(u)du\geq \int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{6}du$$
for some small epsilon.This clearly diverges.